# Can not logout from a menu button with vba

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I login to a webpage and when I try to logout it is just closes the window with

```
ie.Navigate "http://b2b.site.net/el/?mylogout="
ie.Quit
```

and is not logout first
I use the following to logout

```
ie.Navigate "http://b2b.site.net/el/?mylogout="
```

And I tried with the following

```
ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("logout").Click
```

the html part is

```
<div class="header_user_info">
        <a class="logout" href="http://b2b.site.net/el/?mylogout=" rel="nofollow" title="Disconnect me">
        Disconnect
    </a>
</div>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean *"It closes the window with ie.Quit"* - is that a line in your code?

Comment: I mean it goes immediately to ie.quit without run ie.navigate...

Comment: Are you giving it enough time to load? Typically when navigating URLs you need to use something like `While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend` before your next line. If that doesn't work, try `Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:05")`

Comment: Its working I tested 4-5 times, shall I put everytime the delay before I logout? because some sites they seemed to logout normaly. Thank you

Comment: Whenever you're navigating or clicking a button during run-time, you should absolutely use a delay of some sort. I'll add what I use below.

Comment: There is almost certainly a better way. Is this a public url?

Comment: No unfortunately it is a login webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this subroutine when doing any kind of web automation or screen scraping:

```
Sub Wait()

While (IE.Busy Or IE.READYSTATE <> 4): DoEvents: Wend
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

End Sub
```

I've found that the checking the ready state isn't always 100% reliable, so if time isn't of the essence, I use a 2 second buffer.

So in your code it would look like:

```
ie.Navigate "http://b2b.site.net/el/?mylogout="
Wait
ie.Quit
```

Alteratively, if you don't like seeing that extra line:

```
ie.Navigate "http://b2b.site.net/el/?mylogout=": Wait
ie.Quit
```